# IntentService and HandlerThread count

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler, android-looper

I'm trying to understand how intentService do all work in single background thread, as docmentation says. So i dive into source code, and have a question

```
    public abstract class IntentService extends Service {
    private volatile Looper mServiceLooper;
    private volatile ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private String mName;
    private boolean mRedelivery;
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public IntentService(String name) {
        super();
        mName = name;
    }


    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
        mRedelivery = enabled;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO: It would be nice to have an option to hold a partial wakelock
        // during processing, and to have a static startService(Context, Intent)
        // method that would launch the service & hand off a wakelock.
        super.onCreate();
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("IntentService[" + mName + "]");
        thread.start();
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.obj = intent;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    /**
     * You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead,
     * override {@link #onHandleIntent}, which the system calls when the IntentService
     * receives a start request.
     * @see android.app.Service#onStartCommand
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        return mRedelivery ? START_REDELIVER_INTENT : START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceLooper.quit();
}
```

So in onCreate service one HandlerThread is created. After this, all onStartCommand calls adds messages to HanlderThread queue.
But suppose service receive several intents, and adds all to queue. But after handling **first** message, next call after onHandleIntent in handleMessage is **stopSelf(msg.arg1);**. As i understand, after this, service is destroyed, but HandlerThread keep processing messages. And after destroy, suppose i send one more intent to service. Since intentservice is destroyed, **this invoke onCreate and create another HandlerThread!!**, After that there is no Several Worker threads, unlike Single as documentation says. 
Can someone please explain me, where i'am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As i understand, after this, service is destroyed

No. If you call `stopSelf()`, the service is stopped. However, `stopSelf(int)` will only stop the service if there are no other outstanding `Intents` that have been delivered to the service.

Comment: when intentservice is destroyed then?

Comment: @orium: `onStartCommand()` is passed an `int`, typically named `startId`. That is the value you pass to `stopSelf()`, in the same order as they arrive to `onStartCommand()`. Once the last `startId` is passed to `stopSelf()`, the service will be destroyed.